# How should I interpret the "election data"?

Tags: soporte, elecciones

I just downloaded the [election data](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/download-result/1) following the link in the [election page's bottom banner](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/1).

I got a file called `spanish-stackexchange-com-2019-election-results.blt`. Its contents are as follows:

```
0 2
0
"Spanish Language Stack Exchange Moderator Election 2019"
```

That's it.

What does each number mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me bajé los resultados de la [2.ª eleccion de Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/2?tab=election). Allí hubo 9 candidatos para dos plazas y las primeras líneas son así:

```
9 2
1 0 0 1 0
```

Y termina con:

```
0
"Pikoh"
"Alfabravo"
"gbianchi"
"Paul Vargas"
"fredyfx"
"Raul Cacacho"
"Diego Avila"
"Mario Guiber"
"David Villegas"
"Stack Overflow en español Moderator Election 2019"
```

En nuestro caso el fichero contiene:

```
0 2
0
"Spanish Language Stack Exchange Moderator Election 2019"
```

Por lo que la cabecera `0 2`, `9 2`, o `M N`en general, correspondería a "M presentados, N posiciones", donde los *presentados* serían los que concurren a la votación propiamente dicha. No tuvimos elección y el sistema marca 0, no sé por qué. Esto es independiente de que sea elección Pro Tem o no, pues la [elección Pro Tem de Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/election/1) llegó a la fase de votos y también tiene M > 0.

Luego está el 0, que debe aparecer para determinar el final de la contabilidad de los votos, según el paper que describe el método de contabilización de votos: 
http://www.dia.govt.nz/diawebsite.NSF/Files/meekm/$file/meekm.pdf

> The final zero ends the votes.

Y finalmente está la última línea, que corresponde al nombre de la elección.

---

From [Google Code Archive - BLT File Format](https://code.google.com/archive/p/droop/wikis/BltFileFormat.wiki) I see the mention:

> `Droop` uses the `blt` file format, first described by Hill, Wichmann & Woodall in ["Algorithm 123 - Single Transferable Vote by Meek's method"](http://www.dia.govt.nz/diawebsite.NSF/Files/meekm/$file/meekm.pdf)

In the linked paper we read:

> **3.1. The Data**
>
> The data file should be held on disc, or other device that allows quick ‘rewinding’, because it has to be read many times during program execution.
>   Its form should be as follows:
>
> ```
> 4 2
> -2
> 3 1 3 4 0
> 4 1 3 2 0
> 2 4 1 3 0
> 1 2 0
> 2 2 4 3 1 0
> 1 3 4 2 0
> 0
> "Adam"
> "Basil"
> "Charlotte"
> "Donald"
> "Title"
> ```
>
> The first line means that there are 4 candidates for 2 seats. The second line means that candidate number 2 withdrew before the count. As many candidates as nec- essary may be included in this line, each preceded by a minus sign. If no candidate withdrew, the line should be omitted entirely. The third line means that 3 voters put candidate 1 first, candidate 3 second, candidate 4 third, and no more. Each such list must end with a zero. The final zero ends the votes. The subsequent lines name the candidates, in the order of candidate numbers as used in the votes, and finally give a title for the election. If any of these names, or the title, is longer than 20 characters, only the first 20 will be used.
>
> For elections on any substantial scale, further pro- grams are desirable to get the data into this required form. Machine-readable ballot papers would obviously be a great help if a suitable system can be devised.

Comment: Aquí hay un ejemplo de un archivo BLT con comentarios de lo que significa cada cosa: https://www.opavote.com/help/overview

Comment: @walen acabo de editar. Es por el formato del sistema de votos, que describe el paper

Comment: @walen sí, llevas razón.